# rsync not working with Linux Mint 20 as remote

Tags: linux-mint, rsync, remote

I'm using `rsync` for years and have never come upon such a strange issue: everything works fine, unless the remote machine is running Linux Mint 20 (tried with 2 of those, one is still running 20.1 and the other is a fresh & clean install of 20.2). Whether for a single file, an entire directory or just listing resources: `rsync` hangs immediately after negotiation (no matter whether I "push" or "pull"). The very same commands work fine if the remote is a Debian, Armbian, even a Mint 18 (I just switched on an old Laptop to check). Even a simple thing as

```
rsync remote:/path/to/file .
```

hangs. I've experimented with available debug options and saw all goes fine up to the authentication (either via SSH key or password). If I present a wrong password, I get the proper "exit". But if I provide the correct password/key, immediately after authentication the session hangs with no more clues given. The last thing I see is `exec request accepted`. Using `ps` on the remote machine shows the corresponding `rsync` processes have been spawned (and yes, before you ask: connecting to the machine via SSH works fine, even `scp` does its job as expected – just `rsync` does not).

As a last resort and work-around I've started a temporary `rsyncd` on the remote machine:

```
rsync --config=/tmp/rsyncd.conf --daemon --no-detach
```

and then used `rsync remote::share/path/to/file`. While this worked and I got the current task done, I don't want to repeat that everytime I need to sync something.

---

**Edits:**

As one might assume some output from remote `.bashrc` might intervene: `ssh remotehost /bin/true > out.dat` (as the man page suggests for checking) results in a zero-byte file, so this should not be the cause.

`strace`ing the 3 remotely spawned `rsync` processes (which btw all have the same command line, one with and two without a leading `bash`) shows 2 of them ending with `wait4(-1,`, and the other with `{tv_sec=32, tv_usec=23154}`. The "client side" (where `rsync` is invoked by the user) shows, as expected, also a `wait4(-1,`, as it most likely waits for the remote side to respond.

---

**Any ideas what the culprit might be, how to solve the issue,** or even how to further narrow down? As for debugging, I've used `rsync --debug=all4 -avve "ssh -vvv" …` already, which is how I got as far as described.

---

For reference, the `rsyncd.conf` used in above mentioned work-around:

```
use chroot = true
hosts allow = 192.168.0.0/24

transfer logging = true
log file = /tmp/rsyncd.log
log format = %h %o %f %l %b

[share]
comment = Share
path = /mnt/share
read only = no
list = yes
uid = nobody
gid = nogroup
```

Comment: Does `ssh remote hostname` also hang (for your question's value of `remote`)? Or does it correctly return the remote host's hostname

Comment: Does `rsync local/file mint20:/somewhere` fail with the same symptoms? Does `rsync localhost:/path/to/file .` work on the Mint 20 machine? And what about if the ssh connection goes from the Mint 20 machine to another machine?

Comment: `ssh remote hostname` correctly returns the hostname, promptly and without delay. // Doesn't matter if I push or pull, so yes: `rsync localfile mint20:/somewhere` fails the same way as with `localhost`: whenever `rsync` uses ssh and one of the mint20 machines shall deliver, it fails. If I want to push to/pull from e.g. a Debian machine while on mint20, that works fine. IOW, as soon as mint20 has to play the "server part", it fails.

Comment: Can you `strace` the rsyncd process just before you connect?  I'll bet it either hangs or loops when you do.  What's the end of that look like?

Comment: @BowlOfRed I must admit I have no experience with `strace`, so I wouldn't know how to use it. I just prepended `strace` to my `rsync` call, and output indeed stops with `wait4(-1,` – I'd assume it waits for the response from remote, and I'd need to run `strace` there on the spawned process (as the issue only happens with Mint20 **as remote**) – but to which of the 3 processes? One shows no output, one shows `wait4(-1,`, and the 3rd `select(1, [0], [], [0], {tv_sec=32, tv_usec=23154}`. After a while the empty one also shows `wait4(-1,`.

Comment: I doubt running it on the client `rsync` will tell you much.  I think you'd want to try something similar on the server's `rsyncd`.

Comment: Thanks @BowlOfRed, Gilles and roaima – I found the culprit (see my answer below). An ugly side-effect of known bugs never fixed, so one has to work around them. Forgot about that one as it was in place for years already, and never caused any trouble as a "working machine" rarely plays the part of "rsync server"…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the culprit – after I could not reproduce the issue with a 3rd Mint20 machine. Turned out it happened only if one of the Mint20 machines was involved as "server", which narrowed down the search. Ran a `which rsync` there and got a `/usr/local/bin/rsync` back. This (together with a 4th rsync process shown on the "server" end, which I had ignored as I thought it belonging to some other action I run regulary) brought me on-track:

`/usr/local/bin/rsync` was placed to work around an [rsync bug](https://bugzilla.samba.org/show_bug.cgi?id=3653) which is known since 2006 (and still unfixed; find the [script here](https://git.samba.org/?p=rsync.git&a=tree&f=support)). While it solved that nasty problem fine for years as that machine was only used as client, now that the machine needs to be replaced and, for the transfer, acted as server, it back-fired.

To solve the original issue along with the current one, I moved the script to a directory only in the `PATH` of active users but **not** `root` (remote `rsync` is always spawned by root, and that one should get the original `/usr/bin/rsync`). Tested in all directions, seems to work (just need to wait for "that cron job" I applied the original work-around for).

PS: for those using that `rsync-no-vanished` script as well, a minor adjustment solves it. Just change the script to:

```bsh
if [[ $(id -u) -eq 0 ]]; then
    /usr/bin/rsync $@
else
    # original "rsync-no-vanished" script in here
fi
```

That way, when called by root (e.g. the spawned remotes) it simply refers to the original `rsync` binary, and only uses the "work around" for client calls.

---

**PS:** after contacting the project with the details and suggested fix, the script [was quickly updated](https://git.samba.org/?p=rsync.git&a=commit&h=1f0e62f139565f39020e1f76700828b415b01bcf) so similar situations are avoided in the future (thanks to Wayne for the prompt response!).